# Php error 505 & call to undefined functions

Tags: php, visual-studio-2015

I have a php template which I am trying to run using Visual Studio 2015 but when I run the project I get server error 505 and also in the code there are so many call to unknown functions. I tried running other php codes and they work fine. But I can't run this template. get_header() ,have_posts(), get_sidebar('right') all are showing call to unknown functions. This problem is on all pages with all the functions.

```
           <?php 
          get_header();
         global $redux_demo;
         ?>
      <section id="main" role="main">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 right-content">
            <div class="row">
                <?php if($redux_demo['ad1'] != '') {
                    echo '<div class="header_ad">' . $redux_demo['ad1'] .                  '</div>';
                } ?>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <?php if($redux_demo['ad2'] != '') {
                        echo '<div class="header_ad">' . $redux_demo['ad2']   . '</div>';
                    } ?>
                    <div class="main-wrap">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == '1') {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">' . __("The post has been successfully added! If it's not visible, it might require approval from the site administrator!", 'Aruna') . '</div>';
                        }
                        if(isset($_GET['posterror']) && $_GET['posterror'] == '1') {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . __("The post couldn't be added, make sure you filled in all the required fields!", 'Aruna') . '</div>';
                        }
                        if(isset($_GET['register']) && $_GET['register'] == '1') {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">' . __('Registration complete. Please check your e-mail for the password!', 'Aruna') . '</div>';
                        }
                        if(isset($_GET['register']) && $_GET['register'] == 'failed') {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . __('Registration failed! Make sure you filled all the fields and that they are correct.', 'Aruna') . '</div>';
                        }
                        if(isset($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed') {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . __('Login failed! Make sure the username & password are correct!', 'Aruna') . '</div>';
                        }
                        if ( have_posts() ) :
                            $count = 1;
                            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                                if($count == 3 && $redux_demo['ad3'] != '') {
                                    echo '<div class="header_ad ad_between">' . $redux_demo['ad3'] . '</div>';
                                }
                                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                                $count++;
                            endwhile; 
                            get_template_part('includes/pagination');
                        endif; 
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php get_sidebar('right');?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar('left');?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're server instance doesn't support HTTP Protocol. You will need to resolve that first.

[HTTP STATUS 505](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

> **505 HTTP Version Not Supported**
>
> The server does not support the HTTP
> protocol version used in the request.

And Secondly, the functions/methods you're calling in the template are included or not? If PHP compiler doesn't found theme it will throw `undefined function`

Comment: I have used Aruna template and copied all the files in my project still it show me error. I tried in firefox, the only exception is undefined function and if I continue the page is blank